# New user promoting a single service - (subtle) spam?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam-handling, advertising

[This user](https://askubuntu.com/users/1644572/muitotri) was created today, and the user has written 3 answers, of which 2 has been removed as spam *(visible to +10k users)*:

- [How to connect to remote desktop, Kali Linux from ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437654/1066942)
- [Multi-user remote desktop from windows to linux machine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437653/1066942)
- [Multiple users use linux pc at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437688/1066942)

All answers point to the ThinLinc remote desktop solution. This looks like a VNC server/client solution, but it has a subscription fee, which can be seen [here](https://www.cendio.com/thinlinc/buy).

I think it's fairly obvious that this user is advertising a single product. I flagged all 3 posts as spam - the first flag is "disputed", but the 2 second flags have been accepted as helpful. I can live with that - but I still think this is spam - although somewhat subtle, since it's "on-topic" spam.

What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

I also think it's spam.

None of the answers actually try to answer the question except to say "use this product/service".

If the user would actually go into detail about *how* the product/service could answer the question, I would be less likely to define this as spam.  But there has been no real effort to actually answer these questions.  The postings only exist to promote the product/service.

Answer (score 8):

All three of this user's posts have been deleted as spam; this being said, they shouldn't be able to post answers anymore (the anti-abuse system is doing its job)

Answer (score 7):

ThinLinc is 19 years old though.

We used it at university [a long while back]. Yes, it's paid, but it had management features which made it more useful than the bare VNC servers of the day

Not impossible that it's spam (new user, multiple posts, proprietary software; all strong hints) but sometimes people see multiple places where one answer can work and want more points.